# Why can you multiply out?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

$$(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$$
Why is this? Is there a proof to this? And there is something similar in logic.

$$(A \land B)\lor (C \land D)=(A \lor C)\land(A \lor D)\land(B \lor C)\land(B\lor D)$$
Why is this? I used it all my life but I don't know why it works.

Comment: The keyword here is "distributivity." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property .

Comment: Well, it depends on what number (logic?) system you're working in. But with many such systems - the integers, the rationals, the reals - you have a property called *distributivity*, which says that $(a+b)(c)$ = $ac + bc$. Apply this twice, and your identity holds in those number systems.

Comment: The greeks had nice graphic proofs for such things. Look at [this](http://pespmc1.vub.ac.be/POS/turchFigs/IMG.FIG11.1.GIF).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called the **distributive laws** and the **associative laws**.

For numbers, addition and multiplication satisfy the following properties:

**Associativity.** For all $x,y,z$, $(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)$ and $(xy)z = x(yz)$.

**Distributivity of $\times$ over $+$.** For all $x,y,z$, $x(y+z) = (xy)+(xz)$ and $(y+z)x = (yx)+(zx)$.

These are *properties* that these operations satisfy. Not every operation does. for example, subtraction of numbers is not associative, and $+$ does not distribute over $\times$. Your first equation follows from the properties above:
$$\begin{align*}
(a+b)(c+d) &= (a(c+d)) + (b(c+d))  &&\text{(distributivity)}\\
&= \Bigl( (ac)+(ad)\Bigr) + \Bigl((bc) + (bd)\Bigr) &&\text{(distributivity twice)}\\
&= (ac)+(ad) + (bc)+ (bd)  &&\text{(associativity allows the drop of parentheses)}\\
&= ac+ad+bc+bd &&\text{(precedence of operations: $\times$ goes before $+$)}
\end{align*}$$

With logical connectives $\land$ (and) and $\lor$ (or), you have **two** distributive laws: $\land$ distributes over $\lor$:
$$P\land(Q\lor S) = (P\land Q)\lor (P\land S)$$
**and** $\lor$ distributes over $\land$:
$$P\lor(Q\land S) = (P\lor Q)\land (P\lor S).$$

So we have:
$$\begin{align*}
(A\land B)\lor (C\land D) &= (A\lor(C\land D)) \land (B\lor(C\land D))\\
&= (A\lor C)\land(A\lor D)\land (B\lor C)\land (B\lor D)
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 4):

This is a consequence of the [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property). We have that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
(a+b)(c+d) &=& a(c+d)+b(c+d)\\
&=& ac+ad+bc+bd
\end{eqnarray}$$
thanks to left and right-distribution. A similar rule holds in logic, which is discussed in the Wikipedia page I linked to.